# NodeJs with Redis as session store throws exception

Tags: node.js, session, redis, express-session

I was experimenting with NodeJs with Session. I followed code from many sites. Simplest one I would like to mentioned is
[Sample NodeJS Code for session management with Redis](https://medium.com/swlh/session-management-in-nodejs-using-redis-as-session-store-64186112aa9#:%7E:text=The%20session%20ID%20is%20sent%20back%20to%20the,the%20particular%20session%20id%20in%20the%20Redis%20store.)

Rest of the forums found similar to it. Issue I am facing is when I am not using the redis as session store everything work fine. Below changes in code for swithcing from redis session to In memory session.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret$%^134',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
        httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie 
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 // session max age in miliseconds
    }
}))
```

But as I put the Redis store back in sample, I start getting exception ***Client is closed***. Code for enabling the Redis session store is

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
//Configure redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
})
redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
redisClient.on('connect', function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
});
//Configure session middleware
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: 'secret$%^134',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
        httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie 
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 // session max age in miliseconds
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of reading, I got the answer at npmjs site.
[npmjs site for redis-connect package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis)

After version 4, small code change is requried. "legacy-mode" needs to be enabled and explicite 'connect' call need to made in code.

The changed and working code is as below. Added the comments for the changes.

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
//Configure redis client
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    legacyMode:true //********New Addition - set legacy mode to true.*******
})
redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
redisClient.on('connect', function (err) {
    console.log('Connected to redis successfully');
});
redisClient.connect(); //******** New Addition - Explicite connect call *********
//Configure session middleware
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: 'secret$%^134',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, // if true only transmit cookie over https
        httpOnly: false, // if true prevent client side JS from reading the cookie 
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 // session max age in miliseconds
    }
}));
```

Comment: redisClient.get() seems to fail with legacy mode, how do you fix this?

Comment: redisClient.get is working for me without any fixing. Well one thing I would like to mention. redis.Client.get does not return the value. You get the value in callback.  
        client.get('foo',(err, reply) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("############# value got",reply);
    })
Or you have to use getAsync method. Please check thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805128/getting-a-value-from-redis-using-node-js

Comment: I guess in legacy mode it didn’t return a value and in the new mode it does.  I switched to ioredis library to fix for now, thanks for the help confirming the issue!